# Virtualenv activate script won't run in bash script with set -euo

Tags: python, bash, virtualenv

I am trying to create a bash script that activates the virtualenv, pip installs the requirements.txt and continue. This will be my init.sh script for later business.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -euo pipefail

. ${DIR}/scripts-venv/bin/activate
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

where ${DIR} is set to my directory that contains the virtualenv. It seems the issue lies in the above `set -euo` which is the recommended start to bash scripts according to some style guides. More specifically, its the `u` option - interactive that gives the error `/scripts-venv/bin/activate: line 57: PS1: unbound variable`. I can remove it, but was just wondering why this is happening.
Thanks

Comment: what does that echo? tryout with -euxo like this http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=set+-euxo%20pipefail

Answer (score 16):

### If you can update, virtualenv>=16.2  no longer has errors from PS1 not being set

If you are able to update the `virtualenv` library you will find this is now fixed. It was fixed in [pypa/virtualenv/pull/922](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/pull/922), which was included in the 16.2 milestone.

---

### Regarding versions `< 16.2`; and explanation of what you are seeing

`$PS1` is the text that appears in front of the `$` in your bash prompt.  `-u` says that references to unbound variables are errors.  Since `/scripts-venv/bin/activate` refers to `$PS1` and since there's no prompt on an interactive shell then this is an unbound variable and `-u` causes the script to fail.

Maybe this helps:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/170493/login-non-login-and-interactive-non-interactive-shells

When you call a script, the shell that runs that script doesn't have a prompt.  Now, look inside `bin/activate`, line 57:

```
_OLD_VIRTUAL_PS1="$PS1"
```

You can see that `$PS1` is going to get evaluated, and because you have `-u` set, your script can't continue because `-u` says an attempt to do parameter evaluation of an unset variable is an error.

Here are some options for you:

### Option 1: You could fix `bin/activate`

LINE 57:

```
-   _OLD_VIRTUAL_PS1="$PS1"  
+   _OLD_VIRTUAL_PS1="${PS1:-}"
```

Line 61:

```
-        PS1="(`basename \"$VIRTUAL_ENV\"`) $PS1"
+        PS1="(`basename \"$VIRTUAL_ENV\"`) ${PS1:-}"
```

The `:-` syntax causes the expansion to default to an empty string instead of unbound so there's no error.  But this is heavy handed because you're messing with the `virtualenv` created code.

### Option 2: Workaround it

Probably its better just to remove `-u` during the `activate` script.

Try this script, to see what I mean:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -eux
echo "Testing vitualenv"
set +u
. venv/bin/activate
set -u
echo "Test complete $?"
```

By turning off `-u` during activate and then turning it back on again you can just work around the virtualenv awkwardness (if you don't want to fix it).

---

### Option 3 [the future!]

Just update virtualenv so it is version >= 16.2. `pip install --upgrade virtualenv`

Comment: do you know why `$PS1` would be unbound though?

Comment: PS1 is unbound in non-interactive shells because there's no prompt.  `PS1` is the prompt text.  Look here: https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-bash-shell-setup-prompt.html

Comment: I just updated virtualenv but I'm still getting the error. Do I need to create a new virtualenv maybe?

Answer (score -1):

remove the `set -euo pipefail`... it would work just fine