# Snakemake: STAR fails in snakemake but not standalone

Tags: snakemake

Edit, before trying anything, make sure you install Snakemake with:

```
conda install -c bioconda -c conda-forge snakemake
```

As advertised here: [snakemake.readthedocs.io](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started/installation.html). Don't install it as advertised here: [anaconda.org/bioconda/snakemake](https://anaconda.org/bioconda/snakemake), you will end up with a very old version (the -c conda-forge is important!)

**Original post =>**

I have been wrestling with Snakemake today. My problem is that my STAR rule gives me an error:

```
/rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/snakemake/etc/conda/activate.d/activate-binutils_linux-64.sh: line 67: HOST: unbound variable
Error in job star_map while creating output file /rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/preprocessing/180413_NB501997_0054_AHTFJ3BGX3/0054_P2018SEQE15S4_S14.Aligned.out.bam.
RuleException:
CalledProcessError in line 50 of /home/nlv24077/experiments/experiments/swo-406/scripts/Snakefile.snakefile:
Command '
        source activate /rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/snakemake
        STAR         --runThreadN 8         --genomeDir /rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-390/STAR_references/human         --readFilesIn /rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/fastq/180413_NB501997_0054_AHTFJ3BGX3/0054_P2018SEQE15S4_S14_R1_001.fastq.gz /rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/fastq/180413_NB501997_0054_AHTFJ3BGX3/0054_P2018SEQE15S4_S14_R2_001.fastq.gz         --outSAMtype BAM Unsorted         --readFilesCommand zcat         --outFileNamePrefix /rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/preprocessing/180413_NB501997_0054_AHTFJ3BGX3/0054_P2018SEQE15S4_S14.
        ' returned non-zero exit status 1.
  File "/home/nlv24077/experiments/experiments/swo-406/scripts/Snakefile.snakefile", line 50, in __rule_star_map
  File "/rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/snakemake/lib/python3.6/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 56, in run
Exiting because a job execution failed. Look above for error message
```

However, when I just copy that script/command into a terminal, it works.

This is my snakefile:

```
import os
from glob import glob
#from snakemake.utils import validate

configfile: 'config.yaml'
#validate(config, "config.schema.yaml")

# Set the working directory
workdir: config['workdir']

experiment_name = 'swo-406'
scratch_data_base_dir="/rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch"
scratch_data_dir = os.path.join(scratch_data_base_dir, experiment_name)

seqrun = '180413_NB501997_0054_AHTFJ3BGX3'
fastq_dir = os.path.join(scratch_data_dir, 'fastq', seqrun)
preprocessing_dir = os.path.join(scratch_data_dir, 'preprocessing', seqrun)
quantification_dir = os.path.join(scratch_data_dir, 'quantification', seqrun)
if not os.path.isdir(preprocessing_dir):
    os.makedirs(preprocessing_dir)

#ref_base_dir = config[ref_base_dir]
ref_genome = os.path.join(config['ref_base_dir'], config['ref_genome'])
star_ref_dir = config['star_ref_dir']

## Rsem settings
rsem_ref_dir = os.path.join(scratch_data_base_dir, 'swo-387', 'RSEM_references')
rsem_ref_base = os.path.join(rsem_ref_dir, 'Homo_sapiens.GRCh38')

log = os.path.join(preprocessing_dir, 'log.txt')

SAMPLES = set([os.path.basename(fastq_file.replace('_R1_001.fastq.gz', '').replace('_R2_001.fastq.gz', ''))
        for fastq_file in glob(os.path.join(fastq_dir, '*_R*_001.fastq.gz'))
        if not 'Undetermined' in fastq_file])

#star_output_prefix = os.path.join(preprocessing_dir, '{sample}.')

# Rule all is a pseudo-rule that tells snakemake what final files to generate.
rule all:
    input:
        expand(os.path.join(quantification_dir, '{sample}'), sample=SAMPLES)

rule star_map:
    input:
        os.path.join(fastq_dir, '{sample}_R1_001.fastq.gz'),
        os.path.join(fastq_dir, '{sample}_R2_001.fastq.gz'),
    output:
        os.path.join(preprocessing_dir, '{sample}.Aligned.out.bam')
    shell:
        """
        source activate /rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/snakemake
        STAR \
        --runThreadN 8 \
        --genomeDir {star_ref_dir} \
        --readFilesIn {input} \
        --outSAMtype BAM Unsorted \
        --readFilesCommand zcat \
        --outFileNamePrefix {preprocessing_dir}/{wildcards.sample}.
        """

rule samtools_sort:
    input:
        os.path.join(preprocessing_dir, '{sample}.Aligned.out.bam')
    output:
        os.path.join(preprocessing_dir, '{sample}.Aligned.out.sorted.bam')
    shell:
        """
        source activate /rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/snakemake
        samtools sort -T {wildcards.sample} -O bam {input} > {output}
        """


rule rsem_quantify:
    input:
        os.path.join(preprocessing_dir, '{sample}.Aligned.out.sorted.bam')
    output:
        os.path.join(quantification_dir, '{sample}')
    shell:
        """
        source activate /rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/snakemake
        rsem-calculate-expression \
        --paired-end \
        --bam \
        --num-threads 8 \
        --strandedness reverse \
        {rsem_ref_base} \
        {output}
        """
```

Can anyone spot the error?
By the way, I have to comment out

```
validate(config, "config.schema.yaml")
```

Because my snakemake.utils does not seem to have a "validate":

```
(/rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/snakemake) 16:40 nlv24077@kavia /rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406 > python3
Python 3.6.7 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Oct 23 2018, 19:16:44) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from snakemake.utils import validate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'validate'
>>>
```

Highest regards,

Freek.

Comment: What's your snakemake version? `validate` is available [only from `v5.1`](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/configuration.html#validation).

Comment: Wow, seems like I'm on the truly ancient version of 3.13.3! I did a fresh install but perhaps my cluster's conda is old? I'll dive into this, thanx for the tip!

Comment: Hmm, I have an old snakemake but a recent conda, can you explain this:

08:36 nlv24077@lefkimi /rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406 > snakemake --version
3.13.3
(/rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/snakemake) 08:36 nlv24077@lefkimi /rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406 > conda --version
conda 4.5.11
(/rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/snakemake) 08:37 nlv24077@lefkimi /rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406 > conda update snakemake
Solving environment: done

# All requested packages already installed.

Comment: Ok I found the error, so Snakemake to get the latest snakemake, one needs to install with: conda "install -c bioconda -c conda-forge snakemake", not "conda install -c bioconda snakemake".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you remove all the `source activate /rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/snakemake`commands from your shell portions of the different rules in the Snakefile and activate the environment either:

1. run command `source activate /rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/snakemake` before you actually run snakemake on that Snakefile (you can even add a version of snakemake that has `validate` to this environment).  So you can run `source activate /rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/snakemake` and then run `snakemake`.
2. Create a conda environment file matching that environment and add the `conda : path/to/created/env/file`parameter in your rules requiring the environment.  Then run snakemake with the `--use-conda` flag

Since you are using the same environment for all your rules, it is better to use option 1 as option 2 is much slower and will make it unecessarily rule specific.

I can reproduce your error with this example Snakefile:

```
rule test_activate:
        output : "test.txt"
        shell: "source activate NGS && conda list > {output}"
```

I get the same unbound variable error but for a different variable as my environment is different. This is an explanation of what might be going on:

[Virtualenv activate script won't run in bash script with set -euo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42997258/virtualenv-activate-script-wont-run-in-bash-script-with-set-euo)

in the sense that once you run it through snakemake vs terminal some variables become unbound which is treated as error.

Comment: This works indeed! I probably should have mentioned that I use qsub, and I initially got "STAR not found errors", I thought I solved it initially using the "source activate" method. Now I added STAR to the path at the top of my script (export PATH=/rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/tools/STAR-2.6.1a/source:$PATH #this is not conda's star btw) and it works. Somehow I would have thought that it would be good to activate the Snakemake env because it has all my tools. I find it strange that it causes an error and that I have to manually add all tools to my path. But for, now, I'm happy.

Comment: I incorrectly assumed you were using conda.  If it is something you need in most of your submitted jobs you can add `source activate ...`  to `$HOME/.bash_profile` and it will be available when the jobs are submitted.  I usually create a jobscript file and run snakemake with `snakemake --jobscript path/to/jobscript`.  In your case the jobscript can be as simple as the [template](https://bitbucket.org/snakemake/snakemake/src/master/snakemake/jobscript.sh) just change `# properties = {properties}` to `export PATH...` and add any other tools. You can then reuse this jobscript whenever you need.

Comment: Ok, thanx, I will try this. But first I have to find out how I can get my conda to install Snakemake 5.1 instead of 3.13... Thanx for the support so far.